# Creating a chart using chart.js in a .tsx doesn't appear on my web page and I don't know why

Tags: typescript, charts, web-applications

This is the code for the chart

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Chart, ChartType } from 'chart.js';


interface TemperatureData {
  hour: number;
  temperature: number;
}

interface TemperatureChartProps {
  data: TemperatureData[];
}

const TemperatureChart: React.FC<TemperatureChartProps> = ({ data }) => {
  const chartRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartRef.current) {
      const ctx = chartRef.current.getContext('2d');

      if (ctx) {
        new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line' as ChartType,
          data: {
            labels: data.map((entry) => entry.hour.toString()),
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Temperature',
                data: data.map((entry) => entry.temperature),
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
              },
            ],
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
              },
            },
          },
        });
      }
    }
  }, [data]);

  return <canvas ref={chartRef} />;
};

export default TemperatureChart;
```

This is how I call the TemperatureChart in the App file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import TemperatureChart from './components/HourChart'; 
import videoBackground from './assets/video3.mp4';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const handleSearch = (searchTerm: string) => {
    console.log("Search term:", searchTerm);
  };

  const temperatureData = [
    {hour: 1, temperature: 20},
    {hour: 2, temperature: 22},
    {hour: 3, temperature: 24},
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className='App'>
        <div className='tchart'>
          <TemperatureChart data={temperatureData}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the CSS for the chart

```css
.tchart{
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

However, nothing appears on the web page. I am new to this. Any advices on what I'm doing wrong? Most probably has a dumb fix but since I worked with typescript and css for approximatively 3 hours I really can't catch the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itelr.png)
[image: Inspect element errors]

Comment: What do you see when you inspect element on the blank page?

Comment: I edited the post. It shows me this errors.